# How to draw an arraylist of sprites with the same texture? (LibGDX)

Tags: android, libgdx, sprite

My touchDown method:

```
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    float pointerX = InputTransform.getCursorToModelX(GateRunner.WIDTH, screenX);
    float pointerY = InputTransform.getCursorToModelY(GateRunner.HEIGHT, screenY);

    reversers.add(reverserInc, new Sprite(reverser));
    reversers.get(reverserInc).setX(gameIcon.getSprite().getY() / 4);
    reversers.get(reverserInc).setY(gameIcon.getSprite().getY());

    if(reverserInc >= 6)
        reverserInc = 0;

    if(gameIcon.getvX() > 0)
        reversers.get(reverserInc).setPosition(gameIcon.getPosition().x + gameIcon.getSprite().getX(), gameIcon.getPosition().y);
    else if(gameIcon.getvX() <= 0)
        reversers.get(reverserInc).setPosition(gameIcon.getPosition().x, gameIcon.getPosition().y);

    game.batch.begin();
    reversers.get(reverserInc).draw(game.batch);
    game.batch.end();

    reverserInc++;

    gameIcon.negateVelocityX();
    gameIcon.negateRotation();

    return true;
}
```

I want to have an array of Sprites that are all the same texture - that way I can have more than one on the screen. I'm not sure if this is the best way to achieve this but anyways, it is not working. I know when I click it runs through this code because the bottom two methods (gameIcon.negateVelocityX and gameIcon.negateRotation()) are visibly run. Why aren't my reverser sprites being drawn?

Edit (clarification): The intended effect is that when I touch the screen, one sprite will be drawn. Then, when I touch the screen again, another sprite will be drawn. There will be a maximum of 6 onscreen sprites - when there are more than 6, the first ones will be replaced.

Comment: And finally ? Did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you only draw one sprite, that is the sprite of index `reverserInc`.

If you want to draw every sprites stored in an array, you need something like this in your code :

```
game.batch.begin();    
for(int i = 0; i < reversers.size; i++){
        reversers.get(i).draw(game.batch);
    }
game.batch.end();
```

Edit : You need to put this code in your `render()`. If you put this in the touchDown(), your sprites will be drawn only during the touch down event.

Comment: I think my question wasn't worded very well. I have other things in my render() already. The intended effect is that when I touchDown, a "reverser" will be drawn. Then, when I touchDown again, another will be drawn. Basically, I don't want to have too many reversers on the screen so when we get to 6 of them, it will replace the first one, so there is a max of 6 on the screen.

Comment: Furthermore, right now not a single reverser sprite is ever drawn on the screen. Not even one! :(

Comment: In that case, what is sure is that you don't need the `game.batch.begin();
    reversers.get(reverserInc).draw(game.batch);
    game.batch.end()` in the `touchDown()` method. All the drawing must be in the `render()`, and I'd use the method in my answer for that, as it's the method I use to render all the bricks in my brick breaker game from a single sprite. Besides that, I don't know what's the problem in your code. It must be somewhere else than in the touchDown().